# Extracting last two characters from a numeric string

Tags: php

Okay. Say I have string

```
'193'
```

And I want to remove the last numbers and store them in an array so I can do operations with them. I know substr can delete the 2 characters, but I'm not sure how to store them after they've been removed..

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so we can guide you in the right direction? I'm having a tough time figuring out where you're stuck. Do you know how to assign the return value of a function call to a variable? Know how to create arrays? What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I haven't -- I've been thinking about how to do it for about 3 hours and I can't think of anything at all. Haven't tried anything because I can't think of anything...

Comment: Well, what have you got so far - you said you knew how to use `substr()`, can we see how you're using it? How long have you been writing PHP in general? I find it hard to believe that you literally can't think of *anything*...

Comment: I know how to use substr as far as deleting chars from a specific point in the string. I know none-past that.

Comment: I'm just trying to get you to show some code to get an idea of what you're attempting, what you've tried, and where your skill level is at. Something is better than nothing. You won't learn from copy/pasting.

Comment: I am trying to make an RPN calculator for my IRC bot lol. PHP Level: Intermediate Noob?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$end[] = substr("193", -2);
```

Will store "93" in the array $end

Answer (score 5):

Why not treat it as a number (your question said it's a numeric string) ?

```
$last2 = $str%100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = str_split('193'); // $array now has 3 elements: '1', '9', and '3'
array_shift($array); // this removes '1' from $array and leaves '9' and '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "193";
$str_array = str_split($str); 

$number_1 = array_pop($str_array); //3
$number_2 = array_pop($str_array); //9
```